# How to monitor my web application?

Tags: notifications, monitoring, uptime

I'm looking for a tool or set of tools or framework, preferably free, for monitoring different parts of my web app such as the api part, the db connection, the connection to a third-party api which it uses. It doesn't have to be sophisticated, it rather should display "up" or "down" and if it's down then there should be a means of notifying me by email or Slack or the the like. Your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to give a try to the Community Edition of **Pandora FMS**. The *Network server* is focused on [network monitoring](http://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/network-monitoring/) so it can perform TCP checks to port 80 and even send information and check the output back. See this example of the wiki: http://wiki.pandorafms.com/index.php?title=Pandora:Documentation_en:Remote_Monitoring#TCP_Monitoring